# How to access formarray value in the typescript file of angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm unable to access the form array value in typescript file. I'm getting it as blank array
This is my html code

```
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" >
                    <mat-label>Locations </mat-label>
                    <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Fruit selection">
                      <mat-chip
                        *ngFor="let loca of locationlist"
                        [selectable]="selectable"
                        [removable]="removable"
                        (removed)="remove(loca)">
                        {{loca.locationName}}
                        <mat-icon matChipRemove (click)="remove(loca)">cancel</mat-icon>
                      </mat-chip>
                      <input
                        placeholder="Locations"
                        #fruitInput
                        formArrayName="locationctrl"
                        [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                        [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
                        [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                        (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
                    </mat-chip-list>
                    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let locc of locations " [value]="locc"> {{locc.locationName}}   </mat-option>
                    </mat-autocomplete>
                </mat-form-field>
```

i need a method that should return a array value but i'm getting the blank array value

Comment: "I'm unable to access...in typescript file."  And yet you don't show your typescript file.

Comment: can you share your ts file

Answer (score 0):

To get a formarray value or any value from HTML to .ts file is very easy. What you need to do is,
write this code in your HTML file:-

```
 {{log(formarray)}} // or any value you want to log in console.
```

and in your .ts file, you can write this function:-

```
 log(value) {
   console.log(value);
 }
```